# How to pass variables from Python to CMD in Windows

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I am writing a Python (2.5) script that will search through a folder, grab a specific file, and then pass the file and a command to a CMD shell in Windows.  This needs to be done with the command `program.exe /rptcsv <file being created> <file being used>`.  Additionally, the .exe HAS to be executed from the C:\Program Files (x86)\Reporter folder, hence the working directory change.

Here's my problem: I need Python to search for one specific file (fnmatch), and then pass the entire command to a shell.  When this is done correctly, the process runs in the background without launching the GUI.
I've seen the posts about stdin. stdout, etc, and I don't need anything piped back- I just need Python to pass the whole thing.  Right now what happens is Python launches the GUI but fails to pass the command complete with variables.  Is there a way to do this?
I'm still a Python n00b, so please forgive any obvious mistakes.

```
MC01 = 'WKST01*.bat'
MC02 = 'WKST02*.bat'
files = os.listdir(FOLDER)

MC01_CMD = fnmatch.filter(files, MC01)
MC01_CSV = "MC01.csv"

exe = ("reporter.exe /rptcsv", MC01_CSV, MC01_CMD)
os.chdir("C:\Program Files (x86)\Reporter")
os.system("exe")
```

Edit: Earlier in my code, I used os.walk in the FOLDER:

```
print "Walking directory..."
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(FOLDER):
        for file in files:
            pathname = os.path.join(root, file)
```

Because I switched working directories, it's searching for the MC01_CMD file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reporter and (of course) it's not there.  Is there a way to join pathname and MC01_CMD without creating a new variable so it's got the correct location of MC01_CMD?

Comment: For one thing, consider upgrading to a more recent version of python if possible.

Comment: Yeah, I probably should.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[os.system](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) takes a single string as command. In your case, that is the string `"exe"`. You need to concatenate the filenames returnd by `fnmatch.filter`, using `" ".join(exe)` and then call `os.system(command)`. Note the missing " in `os.system(command)`.

For finding the file in a tree, just concatenate the (absolute path of your) base folder of your `os.walk` call with the basedir and the filename. You can filter on the filenames during `os.walk`, too.

```
MC01 = 'WKST01*.bat'
MC02 = 'WKST02*.bat'

def collect_files(folder, pattern):
    for basedir, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
                yield os.path.join(folder, basedir, file)


MC01_CMD = collect_files(FOLDER, MC01)
MC01_CSV = "MC01.csv"

command = "reporter.exe /rptcsv "+ MC01_CSV + " " + " ".join(MC01_CMD)
os.chdir("C:\Program Files (x86)\Reporter")
os.system(command)
```

Comment: Where should I put " ".join(exe)?

Comment: I tried entering it as the next line under `exe = ("reporter.exe /rptcsv", MC01_CSV, MC01_CMD)` and got the error message "TypeError: sequence itm 2: expected string, list found".

Comment: I missed the fnmatch. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: That seems to work but spawned an additional problem.  I've edited my original question with it- can you please look at that?  I'm sorry, I'm not trying to be lazy, it's just that I've been working on this for almost a week now and am very frustrated!

Comment: As an aside, read up on testing and try to split your code into smaller functions, which allow you to better reason about what should happen and compare to what does happen.

Comment: Well, here's what happened: everyone says programming is something you need to do to learn. I had been dabbling with beginner's Python exercises, and suddenly had the genius idea that I would write this script to process my files! That was my "challenge accepted" moment. This has been both fun and horrible at the same time. :D I had no idea you could filter with os.walk, but how wonderful! THANK YOU * infinity!!!!!  I will read up on what you suggested- thanks again!

Comment: Yep, these two together ran exactly what I needed.  You are definitely my hero!  :D

Answer (score 0):

Variables aren't be expanded in string literals. So `os.system("exe")` is the same as typing `exe` in cmd and pressing enter.

So my guess for the correct code would be:

```
MC01_CSV = MC01 + ".csv"

os.chdir("C:\Program Files (x86)\Reporter")
os.system("reporter.exe /rptcsv " + MC01_CSV + " " + MC01_CMD)
```

Comment: When I tried that, I got the error message "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects".

Comment: I see now that fnmatch.filter returns a list of matched filenames.